# Distribution of Number of Digits of Random Numbers

Tags: javascript, python, random

I encounter this curious phenomenon trying to implement a UUID generator in JavaScript.

Basically, in JavaScript, if I generate a large list of random numbers with the built-in `Math.random()` on Node `4.2.2`:

```
var records = {};
var l;
for (var i=0; i < 1e6; i += 1) {
  l = String(Math.random()).length;
  if (records[l]) {
    records[l] += 1;
  } else {
    records[l] = 1;
  }
}
console.log(records);
```

The numbers of digits have a strange pattern:

```
{ '12': 1,
  '13': 11,
  '14': 65,
  '15': 663,
  '16': 6619,
  '17': 66378,
  '18': 611441,
  '19': 281175,
  '20': 30379,
  '21': 2939,
  '22': 282,
  '23': 44,
  '24': 3 }
```

I thought this is a quirk of the random number generator of V8, but similar pattern appears in `Python 3.4.3`:

```
12 : 2
13 : 5
14 : 64
15 : 672
16 : 6736
17 : 66861
18 : 610907
19 : 280945
20 : 30455
21 : 3129
22 : 224
```

And the Python code is as follows:

```
import random
random.seed()
records = {}
for i in range(0, 1000000):
    n = random.random()
    l = len(str(n))
    try:
        records[l] += 1
    except KeyError:
        records[l] = 1;

for i in sorted(records):
    print(i, ':', records[i])
```

The pattern from 18 to below is expected: say if random number should have 20 digits, then if the last digit of a number is 0, it effectively has only 19 digits. If the random number generator is good, the probability of that happening is roughly 1/10.

But why the pattern is reversed for 19 and beyond?

I guess this is related to float numbers' binary representation, but I can't figure out exactly why.

Comment: Some off-topic things: Another way to get that dict: `__import__('collections').Counter(len(str(__import__('random').random())) for i in range(0, 1000000))`.

Comment: if you look at `Math.random().toString(2).length` you'll see a different pattern, perhaps more to what you'd expect

Comment: @KevinGuan And the JavaScript ES6 counterpart (sortof): `Array.apply(null, Array(1e5)).map(() => Math.random()).reduce((records, n) => records[String(n).length] ? (records[String(n).length] += 1, records) : (records[String(n).length] = 1, records), {})`

Comment: A JS version shorter than the previous: `Array.apply(null, Array(1e5)).map(() => Math.random()).reduce((records, n) => (records[String(n).length] = records[String(n).length] + 1 || 1, records), {})`

Comment: @Jaromanda X, binary representation will show a similar effect. It has to do with the difference between number of significant digits and the number of digits needed to represent tiny numbers without using exponents.

Comment: @trincot - `will show a similar effect` - try it and you'll see it's **not** similar at all, about half the results are 55 digits, about 1/4 are 54 digits, about 1/8th are 53 digits and so on - there is no "bump in the middle" to it at all, ever - so, it's about as similar as a grasshopper is to a spark plug

Comment: @Jaromanda X, you are right. The reason is that `javascript` switches to scientific representation for base-10 representations when the number gets very tiny, but it does not make that switch for binary representations. I have added this observation in my answer. Thank you for showing that the effect was not similar.

Comment: You might be entertained by this puzzle, which is based on a related fact about the string representation of random numbers. http://blog.coverity.com/2014/09/17/spot-defect-randomness

Answer (score 8):

The reason is indeed related to floating point representation. A floating point number representation has a maximum number of (binary) digits it can represent, and a limited exponent value range. Now when you print this out without using scientific notation, you might in some cases need to have some zeroes after the decimal point before the significant digits start to follow.

You can visualize this effect by printing those random numbers which have the longest length when converted to `string`:

```
var records = {};
var l, r;
for (var i=0; i < 1e6; i += 1) {
    r = Math.random();
    l = String(r).length;
    if (l === 23) {
        console.log(r);
    }
    if (records[l]) {
        records[l] += 1;
    } else {
        records[l] = 1;
    }
}
```

This prints only the 23-long strings, and you will get numbers like these:

```
0.000007411070483631654
0.000053944830052166104
0.000018188989763578967
0.000029525788901141325
0.000009613635131744402
0.000005937417234758158
0.000021099748521158368
```

Notice the zeroes before the first non-zero digit. These are actually not stored in the number part of a floating point representation, but implied by its exponent part.

If you were to take out the leading zeroes, and then make a count:

```
var records = {};
var l, r, s;
for (var i=0; i < 1e6; i += 1) {
    r = Math.random();
    s = String(r).replace(/^[0\.]+/, '');
    l = s.length;

    if (records[l]) {
        records[l] += 1;
    } else {
        records[l] = 1;
    }
}
```

... you'll get results which are less strange.

However, you will see some irregularity that is due to how `javascript` converts tiny numbers to `string`: when they get too small, the scientific notation is used in the `string` representation. You can see this with the following script (not sure if every browser has the same breaking point, so maybe you need to play a bit with the number):

```
var i = 0.00000123456789012345678;
console.log(String(i), String(i/10));
```

This gives me the following output:

```
0.0000012345678901234567 1.2345678901234568e-7
```

So very small numbers will get a more fixed `string` length as a result, quite often 22 characters, while in the non-scientific notation a length of 23 is common. This influences also the second script I provided and length 22 will get more hits than 23.

It should be noted that `javascript` does not switch to scientific notation when converting to `string` in binary representation:

```
var i = 0.1234567890123456789e-120;
console.log(i.toString(2));
```

The above will print a string of over 450 binary digits!

Comment: It should be noted that Javascript has a [`Number.toFixed()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) when one want to make a mathematical use of the string representation of the number.

Comment: Yes, that is an interesting alternative. For the OP's statistical analysis this might be less useful -- all strings would be have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

It's because some of the values are like this:

```
0.00012345...
```

And thus they're longer.